# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TaskID', table 'TEAM.dbo.Task'; column does not allow nullstement has been terminated

Tags: asp.net

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TaskID', table 'TEAM.dbo.Task'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You cannot just copy-paste an error and expect people to help you out, please check out ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and repost your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to insert the NULL value in the column 'TaskID' which is not nullable, i.e you can't insert NULL value into 'TaskID' column.

Comment: Thanks very much i was able to solve the problem